# Rancher exited after host machine power off and reboot

Tags: docker, centos7, rancher

Can someone explain me why after host machine reboot all containers are exited?How can i find a way to restart containers specially rancher containers and everything be as before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docker restart policy to control container automatic startup. [Check Start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) for more info.

As for the current container that are stopped you need to start them manually:

```
docker ps -a
docker start <container>
```